# What is the simplest way to use 'not in' kind operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 list

```
A=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','t','e','e','e','r','t',','w','w',','r','r']

B=['5','6','7','8','t','e','e','e','r','t',','w','w',','r','r','d','f','w','w','r','r]
```

I have to extract all elements of A which is not present in B

I am trying

```
final=[]
for i in A:
   for j in B:
      if i!= j :
        final.append(i)
```

still i am not getting what i want

Comment: You should use sets if you are not keen on order

Comment: You already know you want `not in`… `if i not in B`.

Answer (score 3):

```
final = [i for i in A if i not in B]
```

Or, if not order nor duplicates are important to preserve:

```
final = set(A) - set(B)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could turn them into type `set`

```py
A = set(A)
B = set(B)
print(A.difference(B))

>>> {'1', '3', '4', '2'}
```

more info [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-set-difference/)